# What is the law for a Goel Hadam (Avenger of Blood) outside of the Land of Israel?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, murder, city-of-refuge

The *halacha* is you can only build a city of refuge in Israel. What if someone killed by accident outside of Israel. Can the relative of the guy who was killed go after and try to kill the murderer who killed by accident?

Answer (score 12):

Sifri states that the Cities of Refuge also serve people who live outside of the Land of Israel. According to [Kesef Mishneh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=89173&rid=12364)'s first explanation, that means exactly what it sounds like: an accidental murderer from another country would have to run away to the nearest City of Refuge in Israel (or Transjordan), and until he does so he would be subject to attack by the goel hadam (the nearest relative of the victim).

Comment: In the modern day, would this mean the most geographically proximate or the one nearest the airport?

Comment: @charles does it matter other than saving the guy's life? If the Goel is lying in wait on the road from the airport to the nearest Miklat, who says he can't go the other way to a different one (or vice versa)?

Comment: I didn't think so, but the answer's wording: `would have to run away to the nearest City of Refuge` implies that.